# Writing unit test for Filter (OncePerRequestFilter) in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, servlet-filters

I have Filter class that extends OncePerRequestFilter. This filter is used for capturing audit data and then pass on to an async method for persisting in db.
I need to write test cases for this entire scenario. How to achieve this? I don't have any great expertise on Junit.

```
public class AuditFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

  private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuditFilter.class);
  private AuditLogManager auditLogManager;
  private String auditMode;
  private List<String> urlPatterns;

  /**
   * @param auditLogManager - processes the audit logs.
   * @param auditMode - modes of auditing (OFF,BASIC,DETAILED).
   * @param urlPatterns - the URL patterns for which auditing to be done.
   */
  public AuditFilter(final AuditLogManager auditLogManager, final String auditMode,
      final List<String> urlPatterns) {
    this.auditLogManager = auditLogManager;
    this.auditMode = auditMode;
    this.urlPatterns = urlPatterns;
  }

  @Override()
  protected void doFilterInternal(final HttpServletRequest request,
      final HttpServletResponse response, final FilterChain filterChain)
      throws ServletException, IOException {
    //capture audit data from request
      try {
        filterChain.doFilter(wrappedRequest, wrappedResponse);
      } finally {
        //capture audit data from response
        // Executing asynchronous call. auditLogManager uses @Async annotation. Need i=integration test for auditLogManager code also
        auditLogManager.log(auditInfo, auditMode);
      }    
  } 
}
```

I need to unit test every action performed by AuditFilter and AuditLogManager(class having asynchronous method) during maven build.

Comment: Your question is confusing. Do you want an unit test or an integration test? Both are completely different. Unit tests are performed against raw Java source code (before deployment). Integration tests are performed against a running server (after deployment). For unit tests you'll need some sort of mocking library (e.g. Mockito) in order to simulate same conditions as on a real running server (this gets really fishy thus). For integration tests you'll need a sophisticated integration testing framework (e.g. Arquillian+Selenium), but you didn't anywhere specify which one you're currently using.

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning it properly. I need a unit test only. These test cases should be executed while I maven build the project. That's all.

Comment: Integration tests are also executed during build.

Comment: I think i need to do as below. First of all I need to test my OncePerRequestFilter. And the asynchronous code invoked from the filter, I need to test separately. is it?

Answer (score 1):

This might be a late response. But an alternate approach that can be used.

With current spring 2.5.5, one option is to use RestTemplate approach

```java
// use below annotation at class level
// the WebEnvironment with Random_port, this is required for test case
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)

@Test
    void postTest() {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        String bodyContent = "{\"appAPI\":\"<SOME-API-CODE-or-USER-NAME>\"}";

        HttpEntity<String> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(bodyContent, headers);
        //END POINT exposed in myapp, which will be used to provide the token.
        String token = restTemplate
                .postForObject("/myapp/authenticate",requestEntity, String.class);

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonNode root;
        try {
            root = mapper.readTree(token);
            JsonNode tokenVal = root.path("jwtToken");
            System.out.println("TKN: "+tokenVal.asText());
            Assert.isTrue(tokenVal.asText()!=null, "Token received successfully");
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            Assert.isTrue(false,"Exception occurred: "+e.getMessage());
        }

    }
```

- In my case, i had a Java POJO for jwt response, so the response from the POST endpoint was a POJO so using ObjectMapper to parse and validate.